# Make target with / at the end?

Tags: makefile, target

I wanted to write a general makefile that fulfils most of my needs for various projects at once. But then I tumbled over the following:

```
%/:
    mkdir -p $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(objects): $$(dir $$@)
```

I expected this to run just fine and create a directory whenever a dir for a target in `$(objects)` does need one. But somehow it didn't work. I checked and found the following: Targets can't end with '/'.

Is there a way I can avoid this?

Comment: It's not true that targets cannot end in "/".  However, make will strip trailing slashes from filenames in some situations, which causes problems.

Comment: I guess .PHONY-targets can? Everything is considered a file, isn't it? I tested the rule `all: something/` and it said no "rule for target something" so I thought it strips every `/` at the end of a target.

Comment: In that rule, `something/` is not the target it's the prerequisite.  If you write a rule like `%/ :` then you run `make -p` to print the rule database you'll see the slash is not stripped from the target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to select an suffix that will can't be the name of a file in the folder. For example `.`. So the rules become the following:

```
%/.:
    mkdir -p $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(objects): $$(dir $$@).
```

As `.` refers to the directory itself this should not create problems what-so-ever :)